# Are API keys and Google Cloud Platform service account credentials safe to store as environment variables in Netlify deploy settings?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless, netlify, netlify-function

I have this app https://github.com/ChristianOConnor/google-cloudfunction-callfromreactapp. It works by simply calling some text via a button press. The text is delivered by a Netlify function. I set up the Netlify function by adding a `netlify.toml` file to the root directory:
netlify.toml:

```
[functions]
  directory = "functions/"
```

and adding this file:
functions/hello-netlify.js:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: process.env.GREETING_TEST,
  };
};
```

I added `GREETING_TEST` environmental variable in Netlify's deploy settings and set it to "this variable is now working":
[image]

The app works perfectly after deploying:
[image]

I have a default python Google Cloud Function that simply prints "Hello World!"

The question is, if I replace the test Netlify function that spits out "this variable is now working," with this,

```
import { JWT } from "google-auth-library";

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const client = new JWT({
    email: process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL,
    key: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
  });
  const url = process.env.RUN_APP_URL;
  const res = await client.request({url});
  const resData = res.data

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: resData,
  };
};
```

set the CLIENT_EMAIL and PRIVATE_KEY to that of my relevant Google Cloud Function service account, and set RUN_APP_URL to the Google Cloud Function's trigger url, would that be safe? My secret environment variables like PRIVATE_KEY would never be visible right?

Comment: Question: Are secrets safe when they are stored in plain text?

Comment: Is it stored in plain text? The "value" of environmental variables in Netlify is asterisked out. I'm assuming that means it's encrypted at rest?

Comment: It is allowed to the authorized accounts. I don't know Netlify storage policy (to confirm the storage at rest). In any case, are you sure enough about the permission management?

Comment: I found this https://www.netlify.com/blog/2021/12/09/use-access-and-share-environment-variables-on-netlify/. This blog entry claims that the environment variables are stored in a "secure, and private location in your project's dashboard?" Do you think that means encrypted?

Comment: It smells good (they talk about secret, and a secret is always kept encrypted). But I didn't find proof!

Comment: Okay awesome thank you very much for your assessment. If you make this as an answer I'll accept it.